# How to enable some choices in the document set form after it is approved

Tags: custom-form

I have a document set and when a user wants to create a new one there is a choice column (radio buttons) in the new document set form. There are 5 choices (a, b, c, d, e)

When the user creates the document set there should only be two options (a, b) and c, d, e must be disabled or hidden.

After the approval of the document set (if it is approved) the user should be able to see c, d, e options (c, d, e becomes enabled).

The Approval system is already working fine. How can I disable the options (c,d,e)?

Please give a detailed answer (SharePoint is new to me).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for this problem.
There are some opensource solutions like [SPSServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns) you can use or [Jquery](http://jquery.com) to manipulate the field.

For more information on how te create [custom document set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg581064%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the very quick answer! I want to use SPServices or Jquery but in any case I think that I need to add the code to the "new document set" form which share point designer says that it is located in _layouts/NewDocSet.aspx. I don,t have access to the server and I know that even I had access to it it is not a good solution to manipulate this file. so what should I do first? where should I write the JQuery codes to see the effect in the new document set form?

Comment: You can create a custom document set in visual studio and a custom docsethomepage.